# How do I load JSON data from multiple URLs stored in an array, one by one?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have an array of urls (selected by the user) from which I want to load JSON data one by one and populate a UITableView. Following is the code I've used but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone provide me with a solution?

```
     while (i < fbPagesURLS.count)
    {

        let newUrl = NSURL(string: fbPagesURLS[i])!
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(newUrl, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                if error == nil
                {
                    print(data)
                    print("----------------------------")
                    i++;
                }

            })
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

It doesn't work so something is definitely wrong. I'd appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake.
Thanks!

EDIT: As advised, I wrote a recursive function. It is working but not all of the JSONs are being displayed. I don't understand what'w wrong.

```
    func loader(let i : Int, var array : [String])
{
    if i < array.count
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: array[i])
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                if error == nil
                {
                    do
                    {
                        let jsondata = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                        print(jsondata)
                        print("--------------------------")


                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }

            })


        })
        task.resume()
        self.loader(i+1, array: array)
    }
    else
    {
        return
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:
Thanks for all the valuable input, guys, I fixed it!.
I enclosed the function call in dispatch_async() and it works fine now.
Here is the updated code:

```
    fbFeedMessages.removeAll()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

        self.loader(fbPagesURLS)

    }
```

Comment: `i++` is not in the correct place. Should be after `task.resume()`.

Comment: If what you need is `one by one?` And its logic use asynchronous processes, the best idea is to use recursive functions.

Comment: I changed the position of the 'i++' and it does print the data now although it's empty

Comment: @jose92405 Okay i'll try a recursive function and give an update here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this , assign your urls to fbPagesURLS and call the loadData method

```
var currentItem = 0
    func loadData()
    {
        if fbPagesURLS.count > currentItem
        {
            currentItem++
        }else{
            return
        }
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(fbPagesURLS[currentItem], completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                if error == nil
                {
                    print(data)
                    print("----------------------------")
                    self.loadData()
                }
            })
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: tried this as well but it's producing similar results. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: it should work,did you check the urls , can you tell me whats happening ?

Comment: yes the urls are correct, I checked by printing them to the logs. I honestly don't know what's wrong. Could it be a problem with dispatch_async?